# How to set a visible div inactive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a web application with jQuery and here I have multiple items that the user can drag´n drop around, unfortunately I also have another item, which needs to be on-top of all draggable items with a higher z-index. If I place one of the draggable items behind the covering item, I can not drag it anymore.

Is there a way to set that covering item somehow inactive, so that it is still visible ?

Comment: You want the dropped item to be behind but still draggable?

Comment: Can you check where the item is been dropped. It is inside the covering item (with high z-order) or along other dropped items?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements